# RESTEasy mapping parameter with '-' in their name

Tags: jboss7.x, resteasy

A simple question (I hope so...) for RESTEasy experts. 
I receive a form posted via POST which contains attributes with '-' in their names :
Example :
`return-code=12`

I want to map all the content of this POST into a Pojo :

```
public class MyFormInfo {
    public String attr1="";
    public String return_code=""; // don't work because return-code is not mapped in return_code
...
```

The method declaration is the following :

```
@POST
@Path("/return-cic-payment")
public String receiveForm(MyFormInfo form) throws Exception {
    log.info("Return-code is : {}", form.return_code);
}
```

I don't to map attributes one by one in the parameters lists because the form contains a large number of fields.

Because I can't have an attribute named "return-code" in my POJO, I wonder how to do toget this parameter's value.
A custom mapping can be a solution, but I don't know how to achieve that.
Other idea I try without success, to receive a Map of attribute.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/#_Form

```
class MyFormInfo{
  @FormParam("return-code") 
  private String returnCode;
  //etc.
}
```